# gorm how to do insert with a has one relation that already exists

Tags: go, go-gorm

```
package main

import (
    "time"

    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/logger"
)

type Country struct {
    ID        int
    Name      string `gorm:"uniqueIndex"`
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}
type Operator struct {
    ID        int
    CountryID int
    Country   Country
    Name      string
    Code      string
    CreatedAt time.Time
    UpdatedAt time.Time
}

func main() {
    config := gorm.Config{
        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info),
    }
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &config)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Country{}, &Operator{})
    test1 := Operator{Country: Country{Name: "Test"}, Name: "Test1", Code: "A"}
    db.Create(&test1)

    test2 := Operator{Country: Country{Name: "Test"}, Name: "Test2", Code: "B"}
    db.Create(&test2)

}
```

With the above code, test1 creates a new Country and Operator and the operator_id is correct in the xqlite database.

With test2 however, operator_id is set to 0. What should I do to create the test2 entry and have it refer to an existing Country ?

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `db.Create(&test2)` is likely failing due to the `uniqueIndex` constraint on `Country`. Make sure to check your errors!

What you may find to work is to insert a single `Country` entry into the DB first, like so:

```golang
testCountry := Country{Name: "Test"}

if result := db.Create(&testCountry); result.Error != nil {
  // do something with result.Error
}
```

Based on my most recent experience working with Gorm, `db.Create` will populate `testCountry.ID` assuming it succeeds (always check your errors!). After that, create `test1` and `test2` like so:

```golang
test1 := Operator{
  Country:   testCountry,
  CountryID: testCountry.ID,
  Name:      "Test1", 
  Code:      "A",
}

if result := db.Create(&test1); result.Error != nil {
  // do something with result.Error
}

[... do the same thing with test2 ...]
```

Comment: Also, obligatory Gorm docs link on this topic: https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Create-With-Associations

It's not super duper helpful, but I gotta post it.

Comment: Yes, it's failing due to the unique constraint - so I was wondering if there was a way for gorm to handle this. The docs are not super helpful in this regards, even the https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html doesn't say anything about how to handle this, that has to be a common case  - surely you don't want every user you insert to the DB to create a new Company - as the example is about. But if the way is to just always query for an existing Country in my case, I'll do that.